# How to modify the output of cited news articles in text with biblatex (Full date and name of news magazine)

Tags: biblatex, newspaper

I have one week left for handing in my thesis and I have quite a big problem. I cite a lot of Online-Newspaper Articles but in the text it looks like:

> Text (Hürriyet Daily News 2013)

The output SHOULD be like this:

> Text (Hürriyet Daily News vom 16.03.2013)

For my bibliography I am using biblatex with the author-year style luh-ipw from CTAN.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@newspaper{SZ.2013a,
    Author = {{S{\"u}ddeutsche.de}},
    Date = {2013-10-29},
    Day = {29},
    Month = {10},
    Year = {2013},
    Title = {T{\"u}rkei er{\"o}ffnet Bahntunnel unter dem Bosporus},
    Url = {http://www.sueddeutsche.de/auto/nach-fast-zehn-jahren-bauzeit-tuerkei-eroeffnet-bahntunnel-unter-dem-bosporus-1.1806910},
    Urldate = {2013-10-30}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-luh-ipw
]
{biblatex}

\bibliography{bibliographie}

\begin{document}

\parencite{SZ.2013a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I added the new type @newspaper thanks to the advice in the comments.

So far so good, in the bibliography everything works as expected BUT: In the text I need to print the full date and have no idea how to modify the biblatex style accordingly.

Comment: You might like to provide us with an actual [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/), not just these two short snippets of code, so we can have a proper look at your question and hopefully a successfully stab at answering it. Do you want only `@misc`s to have the full date or all entries that have that particular information available (or do you want that only those `@misc`s that are newspaper articles)? It might be better to define a new (sub)`type` or `entrytype` for these newspaper articles.

Comment: Thanks! I created a newspaper type and it seems to compile normal like misc in the main document. I updated the question section and added a MWE.

Comment: I assume it is possible to trigger the output for one specific type? Seems clever but I have no clue how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. By default the date of any citation command is printed by the following definition:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

That means you have no options influencing the style. So instead of `year` I am using `\printdatelabel` which allows some modification by the option `datelabel`. And only for the entrytype `newspaper` the new definition is used:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@newspaper{SZ.2013a,
    Author = {{S{\"u}ddeutsche.de}},
    Date = {2013-10-29},
    Title = {T{\"u}rkei er{\"o}ffnet Bahntunnel unter dem Bosporus},
    Url = {http://www.sueddeutsche.de/auto/nach-fast-zehn-jahren-bauzeit-tuerkei-eroeffnet-bahntunnel-unter-dem-bosporus-1.1806910},
    Urldate = {2013-10-30}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw,datelabel=terse]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{newspaper}{article}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {%
     \ifentrytype{newspaper}%
         {%
          \printtext[bibhyperref]{vom~\printdatelabel}%
         }%
        {%
         \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}%
        }%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\parencite{SZ.2013a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image]