# Modifying citation style for newspaper articles in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

To elaborate on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144387/how-to-modify-the-output-of-cited-news-articles-in-text-with-biblatex-full-date) example, I have this code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@newspaper{SZ.23.06.2014,
 author = {Gammelin, Cerstin and Hulverscheidt, Claus},
 year = {2014},
 title = {Sozialisten nennen Preis für Juncker},
 pages = {1},
 pagination = {page},
 journal = {Süddeutsche Zeitung},
 month = {23.06.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw,datelabel=terse]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{newspaper}{article}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {%
     \ifentrytype{newspaper}%
         {%
          \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{month}\printfield{year}}%
         }%
        {%
         \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}%
        }%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\parencite{SZ.23.06.2014}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

which gives me the following output (note the additional space within the parentheses):

[image]

What I want to do is to cite newspaper articles by the newspaper (not the actual author), something like this:

> (Süddeutsche Zeitung 23.06.2014, S. 11)
>
> **Literatur**
>
> Süddeutsche Zeitung (23.06.2014) = Gammelin, Cerstin und Claus Hulverscheidt : Sozialisten nennen Preis für Junker. In: Süddeutsche Zeitung 23.06.2014, S. 11.

I did have a look at the Biblatex documentation, but I'm kind of confused with Biblatex's macro structure. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can get rid of the evil space by using the correct way to enter dates in `biblatex`: either just `date = {2014-06-23}`, no `year`, `month` or `day` field; or `year = {2014},` `month = {6}`, `day={23}` (obviously the former is somewhat shorter and - I think - more readable). If you need another date format than the one you get if you use the `date` field, have a look at the `date` option and its friends (pp. 51 sq. in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)): you probably want `date=short`.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually found the suggestion of misusing the `month` format somewhere. Could you give me a hint about the second part of my question?

Answer (score 3):

You have only adjusted the format of citations and not of the printed date in the bibliography.  Also you are misusing the `month` format, the day should be put in a separate `day` field.  Here is an example including an article entry to show that we are only changing the format of news paper entries.

*Update* to address your citing format for these entries I have add code to modify the standard `cite` macro from `authoryear-icomp.cbx` to first test wether the type of the entry is `newspaper` and the to apply appropriate formatting.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@newspaper{SZ.23.06.2014,
 author = {Gammelin, Cerstin and Hulverscheidt, Claus},
 year = 2014,
 title = {Sozialisten nennen Preis für Juncker},
 pages = {1},
 pagination = {page},
 journal = {Süddeutsche Zeitung},
 month = 6,
 day=23
}
@Article{test-art,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  year =     2014,
  volume =   4,
  number =   2,
  pages =    {1--20},
  month =    6,
  day =      20
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-luh-ipw,datelabel=terse]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{newspaper}{article}
\addbibresource{bibliographie.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {%
     \ifentrytype{newspaper}%
         {%
         \printtext[bibhyperref]{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{day}}\adddot
         \mkdatezeros{\thefield{month}}\adddot\printfield{year}}%
         }%
        {%
         \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}%
        }%
   }%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[newspaper]{date}{\mkdatezeros{\thefield{day}}\adddot
         \mkdatezeros{\thefield{month}}\adddot\printfield{year}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{% Modified from authoryear-icomp.cbx
  \ifentrytype{newspaper}{\printtext{\printfield{journaltitle}\addspace\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}\addcomma\addspace \printfield{pages}}%
  }
  {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
          {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
             {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                          \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
                {\setunit{\addcomma}%
                 \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
                {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
                 \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
                 \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
             {\printnames{labelname}%
              \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
              \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parencite{SZ.23.06.2014} and \parencite{test-art}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew (unfortunately, I cannot vote you up yet). Like I have noted above, I had found the suggestion of misusing the month format somewhere. Could you give me a hint about the second part of my question?